# django + own database switch MySQL error

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, database-connection

Hello Im changed my database in settings.py from default sqlite to mysql and I got problem. I installed mysqlclient, mysql-python on virtualenv and it's doesnt work

My example database connection

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': 'dev.website.eu',
    'USER': 'name',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'NAME': 'database_name',

 },
 'sqlite': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
```

}

When I changed database i got a error in terminal

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb 
module: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

Anyone know how to change that error? If I put those data in mysql-connector it's work but when I want connect via settings.py it doesnt work

Comment: is that mysql package installed on your linux system?

Comment: yes, I reinstalled MySQLdb 
      pip uninstall MySQL-python
And tried to install 
      pip install libmysqlclient-dev 
and its doesnt install but when i write 
     pip install mysql-python 
its succesfull installed but still doesnt work

Comment: It seems it doesn't find mysqlclient package or mysql-python package, check if you have activated your virtualenv. Sometimes I forgot to activate virtualenv and happens this kind of things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you don't need it anymore, remove :

```
 'sqlite': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
```

Then, what version of Python do you use ?

A more complete conf :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '**',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },        
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed sqlite in databases settings and I added conf to default mysql and I got still that error

I use a Python 3.5.3 and django 1.11.1

Comment: what is the version of Python do you use ?

Comment: Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux

Comment: Ok but when you call python --version ? Because if you run Django with  python manage.py runserver and the python path is python 2, so you use Python 2.

Comment: I use virtualenv, when i put python command i got python 3.5.3. If i deactivate virtualenv i got python 2.7.13 on command python and python 3.5.3 on python3

Comment: Ok so I have to tell you, last time I used mysqlclient, it was not well supported in Python3. there are some forks of mysqlclient which could be better for you.

Comment: I installed django on my virtualenv via 
     sudo pip2 install django 
and I reboot'ed server via
     python2 manage.py runserver  
and its works ;)
 Thank you GrandGTO.

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer to solve the issue.